# apache24/PHP8 windows 10 localhost Unable to connect

Tags: php, apache, web, port

Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:
Port Listen **8080**
[image: I have added the php 8 module]
[image: index.php set]

[image][image]

I have set everything and tried port :80 and :8080, both doesn't work, what am I missing?

Comment: Do you have any other servers already using ports 80 and 8080?  IIS, nginx, other...

Comment: Is it possible that you either don't have a "logs" directory inside `C:\Apache24` or Apache doesn't have access to this directory somehow?

Comment: @JamesYoung yes I have worked with `npm run dev`

Comment: @Catalyst I manually opened the Apache24/logs/error.log | access.log | install.log nothing productive written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked properly now.

### steps on how it worked

**Legend:** IPv4Address: 192.168.1.5 it should be different on your machine

- `cmd>ipconfig`
- copy IPv4Address
- open Apache24/config/httpd.conf
- line 59: `Listen IPv4Address:8000`
- line 60: `Listen 8000`
- line 218: `ServerName IPv4Address:8000`
- save file
- `cmd> cd C:\Apache24\bin`
- `cmd>./httpd` for me httpd without ./httpd didn't work for some reason
- refresh http://localhost:8000 or http://IPV4Address:8000 and it should work!

I think because I had run `cmd>npm run dev` ports 80 and 8080 were taken (although the server is offline now), luckily port 8000 is free.
Thanks @JamesYoung

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your computer process.

Below are the process check command

```
# for window
tasklist | findstr "httpd"

# for linux
ps -ef|grep httpd
```

Comment: httpd.exe                     6844 Console                    1     14,752 K
httpd.exe                     7444 Console                    1     30,864 K